# How to best pass an object into .Net from Coldfusion for system migration

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion, migration

I'm trying to find some clarity on an area which seems to have very little the way of documentation aside from some adobe documentation on using `cfobject`. In an effort to migrate an organization from Coldfusion to .Net, what would be the best way to get that data into .Net applications? I had looked into the CF gateway for .Net or simply using XML to pass data into .Net from coldfusion. For initial starters, the data represents reports and results from calculations performed on the coldfusion side. The idea is to ease people into the .Net platform and UI rather than just spring a whole new system on them out the gate.

Comment: Are you trying to incorporate .NET into Coldfusion or do you want to have a separate .NET application?

Comment: I'm planning for a .Net application. Initially I want to pass data (web forms, strings, and queries) into .Net from Coldfusion and have .Net perform some smaller functions and serve as a UI. For example, I need to take CF form field values and pass them into .Net where they can be converted into a PDF. That's one of the smaller pieces.

Comment: You can use [.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). It accepts a variety of data inputs like forms, xml, and json. Then you can use REST in Coldfusion to communicate with .NET.

Comment: Make it a web service.  The rest is details.